# select elements in dropdown marked as a list

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to loop through all elements inside of a dropdown box...however unlike a typical html box with  values, these are all UL/LI's.  Here is what the html looks like:

```
<ul class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-corner-bottom jfpw-select ui-selectmenu-open" aria-hidden="false" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="currentStatementsDate-button" id="currentStatementsDate-menu" aria-activedescendant="currentStatementDateOptions" tabindex="0" style="width: 328px; height: 160px; float: left; overflow: hidden; outline: none; z-index: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: relative; border-style: none;">
   <li role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" id="currentStatementDateOptions" class=""><span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">Unbilled</span></li>
   <li role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true" id="currentStatementDateOptions" class="ui-selectmenu-item-selected"><span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">September 10, 2015</span></li>
   <li role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" id="currentStatementDateOptions" class=""><span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">August 12, 2015</span></li>
   <li role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" id="currentStatementDateOptions" class=""><span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">July 10, 2015</span></li>
   <li role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" id="currentStatementDateOptions" class=""><span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">June 10, 2015</span></li>
   <li role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" id="currentStatementDateOptions" class="ui-corner-bottom"><span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">May 12, 2015</span></li>
</ul>
```

I need to somehow select each of the list items...but since these are different from a typical dropdown I am not sure.

I'm guessing I need to change the attributes (aria-selected) and class (the selected) for each interation but am not sure how to proceed since they all have the same id.

Comment: Yeah... if that's a site that your company owns, you might talk to dev and tell them that HTML standard dictates that the ID should be unique on the page... but I'm guessing that you don't control the site and/or they don't care... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to get the collection of `LI`s and loop through the collection executing `.click()` (and whatever else) on each. This can be easily accomplished using the code below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("currentStatementsDate-menu")).click();
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#currentStatementsDate-menu > li"));
for (WebElement option : options)
{
    option.click();
    // do something here? validations, etc.
}
```

The CSS selector `#currentStatementsDate-menu > li` reads find an element with an `ID` (#) `currentStatementsDate-menu` that has children (>) that are `LI`s.

Read more about [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

---

EDIT 1:
I bet you have to click the "dropdown" first before you can click the elements inside. Added the initial click.

Comment: I get this error- 'org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible' when trying option.click

Answer (score 1):

I would find the List of the WebElements and use nt-child with increasing the `nth-child()` function

```
#currentStatementsDate-menu>li:nth-child(1)
```

Something like this:

```
By css = By.cssSelector("#currentStatementsDate-menu>li");
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(css);

for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    By by = By.cssSelector(String.format("#currentStatementsDate-menu>li:nth-child(%s)", i+1));
    driver.findElement(by).click();
}
```

Comment: You already found the collection of `LI`s in `elements`, why search for them again when you click?

Comment: You are right, it's bit redundant. I was just showing the point of using `nth-child()` function

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use jquery to loop through the elements:

```
var test = $("#currentStatementsDate-menu").children().each(function() {
    var li_element = $(this);
    console.log(li_element);
});
```

Also, I am not sure if having the li elements with all the same ids is correct.